# Нужны ли кавычки? (1)

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

`Слышу крики («)помоги(»).`

Нужны ли кавычки? Такой вопрос меня очень интересует-таки.

Comment: Что с вами, уважаемый?

Comment: Максим, уберите, пожалуйста, ТАКИ.  Моя личная  просьба. Эта частица разговорного стиля, да и там ее использование надо объяснять. У нас же  при формулировке вопроса стиль книжный, разговорный допускается в комментариях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

да, нужны

> Слышу крики: «Помоги...»

> Слышу крики: «Помоги!»

> И я затем услышал вдруг крик «помогите!». (Нет паузы перед криком.)

> И я затем услышал вдруг крик: «Помогите!» (Есть-таки паузчонка.)

Comment: Хорошо. Но варианты с двоеточием мне не подходят. :)